# Не работают вложенные стили Aphrodite-jss

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В aphrodit-jss реализованы вложенные стили.

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'aphrodite-jss';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        color: 'black',
        '& div': {          // Вложенный селектор
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
});
```

Все прекрасно работает, но когда пытаюсь обратиться по классу, то стили не применяются:

```js
'& .logo': {
    color: 'red'
}
```

Пробовал ещё так:

```js
'&.logo': {
    color: 'red'
}
```

Так:

```js
'& logo': {
    color: 'red'
}
```

И так(нарушение синтаксиса):

```js
logo: {
    color: 'red'
}
```

Как можно обратиться по классу во вложенных стилях aphrodite-jss.

Comment: '& .logo' такая запись работает https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-architecture-gudi2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Понятно, у меня вложенный класс тоже был сделан через css(styles.some)